# Google Chrome extension - popup not showing and can't inspect background page

Tags: typescript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing Chrome Extension that extracts spreadsheet id from active tab and manipulates Google Sheets via gAPI. I can't identify specific circumstances during which this bug shows up. After some successful usages of the extension the popup just can't be open again, but the extension icon's background becomes gray.

The only way to work around this problem is reloading the extension in *Developer mode*. In the same version uploaded for testing to Chrome Web Store - removing and adding again extension fixes nothing. Error collector seems to catch no errors, but when clicking `Inspect views background.html`, in inspection window title bar there's this strange URI thing from second screenshot instead of `DevTools - chrome-extension://<id>/background.html`. After reload `DevTools - chrome-extension://<id>/background.html` is in the title bar again.

Tried to solve this problem by switching between `page_action` and `browser_action` in the manifest file (with proper changes in `background.ts`). No effect.

**background.ts**

```
import {BackgroundServiceFoo} from "../BackgroundServiceFoo";
import {BackgroundServiceBar} from "../BackgroundServiceBar";

(window as any).backgroundServiceFoo = new BackgroundServiceFoo();
(window as any).backgroundServiceBar = new BackgroundServiceBar();

function tokenRefresh() {
  (window as any).backgroundServiceFoo.tokenRefresh()
    .catch(console.error);
}

chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.removeRules(undefined, function() {
  chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.addRules([{
    conditions: [new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
      pageUrl: {urlContains: 'docs.google.com/spreadsheets'},
    })
    ],
    actions: [new chrome.declarativeContent.ShowPageAction()]
  }]);
});

chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener(tokenRefresh);
chrome.alarms.create("tokenRefresh", {periodInMinutes: 30});
tokenRefresh();
```

**index.ts** uses service from background script like:

```
chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage(backgroundPage => {
  ((backgroundPage as any).backgroundServiceBar as BackgroundServiceBar).doStuff();
});
```

[image: chrome://extensions]
[image: Non-functional inspection]

Comment: 1) When the icon is gray it means your chrome.declarativeContent rules didn't match. It can happen on modern sites that use HTML5 History API for navigation. The common fix is to switch to a generic rule e.g. `hostEquals: 'docs.google.com'`, 2) chrome.declarativeContent should be used inside chrome.runtime.onInstalled as shown in the documentation.

Comment: Hi @wOxxOm, thank you for quick answer.
1) I wrote "extension icon's background" - I meant this gray circle that becomes the icon's background when the popup is open, not grayscale version of icon when on "wrong" tab.
2) I changed it and unfortunately it's not the case.

Comment: Sounds like the extension has stuck in infinite loop. Check CPU consumption of the extension in process manager (either of the OS or the built-in one in Chrome). Also try switching to messaging because direct invocation of functions from another window may be buggy and anyway it's harder to debug.